# app crash on call .dll in delphi

Tags: delphi, dll

I have a DLL it crated with Delphi xe10.2 and it contain a function

```
function calc(b : integer;a:integer) : Integer;
begin
  Result := a+b;
end;
```

and i will call it on other program like this

```
function calc(b : integer;a:integer): Integer; stdcall; external 'my.dll';
```

i copied the DLL in System32 folder and application .exe folder

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
 showmessage(inttostr(calc(2,3)));
end;
```

but when i run from delphi IDE nothing happened.it dont show any error and also dont show application main form...

how can i fix this ?!

Comment: You're not exporting function with `stdcall` but `register`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

System32 is the 64-bit system folder. Your application is a 32-bit application, and hence does not search for DLLs in System32. It will search in SysWOW64 instead, which is the 32-bit system folder. If you ran the program without debugging, you would see an error message telling you that the DLL could not be located.

Now, you should never modify the contents of system folders. Remove the DLL from System32 and instead place it in the same directory as your executable file.

The other problem, given the code shown, is that the exported DLL function uses the `register` calling convention, but you import it using the `stdcall` calling convention. You must ensure that the calling conventions used by DLL and EXE match each other.

Comment: i changed `stdcall` to `register` and then removed `my.dll` from every where, but nothing changed, i also used `run without debugging` but it dont show any error yet!

Comment: Personally I'd use stdcall everywhere because it is understood by tools other than delphi. You place the dll in the same directory as the executable. Did you do that? Then run the executable directly. It's frustrating to give advice and it is seemingly ignored.

Comment: ok,when i run the app from executable directly it work,also when i copy the dll on source directory it work when run from ide!!

Comment: when i used `stdcall` the result of `calc` 2 and 3 was 81095 but when i changed it to `register` the function returned 5 .

Comment: You need the calling convention to match on both sides. Use `stdcall` in the DLL code, and `stdcall` in the executable code.

Comment: yes,but how can i know when use `stdcall` or when use `register` when i got a dll from other language like c ?

Comment: For the n-th time, the calling conventions have to match. When you call a third party dll, you need to look at its sdk to find out the calling convention.